# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, почему не импортируется таблица в phpmyadmin.
Структура:
Таблица товаров

Таблица категорий

Я пытаюсь из xml дампа другой таблицы (она идентична с этой) импортировать данные, но выходит ошибка

Все категории с такими же ид есть в базе. Почему он не может связать их?

Вопрос решен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер ничего выдумывать не станет. Если он говорит, что в родительской таблице нет соответствующих записей - значит, их действительно нет. Выполните запрос

```
SELECT child.reference_field
FROM child
LEFT JOIN parent ON child.reference_field = parent.reference_field
WHERE parent.reference_field IS NULL
```

и смотрите, какие именно значения отсутствуют.

PS. Если у Вас child-таблица в XML - лучше импортируйте её в несвязанную временную или статическую, и потом уже смотрите, с какими записями проблемы.

Comment: Я сделал ваш запрос (только is not null поставил) `SELECT hp_products.category_id
FROM hp_products
LEFT JOIN hp_brands ON hp_products.category_id = hp_brands.id
WHERE hp_brands.id IS NOT NULL`. Добавил в таблицу hp_products 1 товар, и в результате вот что `category_id 23`. Все правильно.Вернулась та категория к которой относится товар. Так же при импортировании, импортируемый товар имеет эту же категорию, но сервер ругается...

Comment: Ага... "я ни хрена не понял, поэтому сделал по-своему"...